# Angular dart - select with an Object as model (not string)

Tags: angular, select, dart

I'd like to do something like:

```
<select id="country" name="select" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="form.country">
  <option *ngFor="let country of form.allCountries" [value]="country">
{{country.name}}
  </option>                                                        
</select>
```

I expect `form.country` to be a `Country` (the same type as the items in `form.allCountries`) but it is a `String`.

Is there any way to have something else than a `String` with a select?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use ngValue :

```
<select id="country" name="select" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="form.country">
  <option *ngFor="let country of form.allCountries" [ngValue]="country">
      {{country.name}}
  </option>                                                        
</select>
```

the difference between value and ngValue :

```
[value]="..." only supports string values
[ngValue]="..." supports any type
```